# Function spaces in which every function has a unique antiderivative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $X$ denote the set of all smooth functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f''=-f$. Then $$X = \{a \sin + b \cos : a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$ Ergo, the following hold:

- $X$ is a linear subspace of the space of smooth functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
- $X$ is closed under differentiation.
- For all $f \in X$, there's a unique $g \in X$ such that $g' = f$.

This $g$ can be denoted $\int f(x) dx$. For example: $$\int \cos(x) dx = \int_0 \cos(x)dx, \qquad \int \sin(x) dx = \int_0 \sin(x)dx-1$$

It's a bit like the fixed but arbitrary constant is chosen for us.

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** Is there a name for function spaces with the above three properties?
>
> **Q1.** Which differential equations give rise to such function spaces?
>
> **Q2.** Given a set $S$ and a function $f : S \rightarrow S$, is there a term for those subsets $X$ of $S$ satisfying the following?
>
> - For all $x \in X$, the set $f^{-1}(x) \cap X$ has precisely one element.
>
> This is equivalent to the following two conditions:
>
> - $f(X) \subseteq X$
> - The function $X \rightarrow X$ obtained by restricting $f$ to $X$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

What you did is to equip the null space of the operator $f''+f$ with a basis, such that the differentiation operator written in this basis is an invertible 2x2 matrix.

I suspect this works for all linear differential operators with constant coefficients. The basis of the nullspace of such operators consists of  functions of the type $e^{zt}$ (complex case) or $e^{(a+ib)t}\pm e^{(a-bi)t}$ (real case). Now differentiation translates to multiplication with a diagonal matrix (complex case) or block-diagonal matrix of 1x1 or 2x2 blocks (real case). The inverse operator (integration) is then well-defined and yields a unique element.